# Can't map JSON object to ViewModel (knockout js)

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm receiving json data from WCF service and want to map it to my viewModel.

***JSON DATA:***

```
  {"bios" :
        { "Caption" : "something",
          "Version": "something else",
           ....
        }
    }
```

My **HTML** part is the following:

```
<ul class="biosContentUL">
              <li class="biosContentLI">
                  <p>
                     <b>Caption: </b><span data-bind="text: bios.Caption"></span>
                  </p>
                </li>

               <li class="biosContentLI">
                    <p>
                     <b>Version: </b><span data-bind="text: bios.Version"></span>
                    </p>
                </li>
               .......
</ul>
```

My **ViewModel** is the following:

```
var viewModel = {
    bios: ko.observable(),
    cpu: ko.observable(),
    .....
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
}
);
```

I'm trying to use mapping plugin, but can't make it work correctly.

```
function showBios() {
var response = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        datatype: "json",
        url: "...",
        success: function (data) {
            objJS= jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            viewModel.bios(ko.mapping.fromJS(objJS));

             // I also tried this:
            //  ko.mapping.fromJS(objJS, {}, viewModel);
        }
      });
```

The following code works, but I also have observableArrays in my ViewModel, so I loose their content if I call applyBindings() one more time.

```
viewModel.bios = ko.mapping.fromJS(objJS);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

How can I map received data to my viewModel property "bios" ? Is it a good approach to have multiple viewmodels for each part of the page, so in each model I can declare simple properties, not complex objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally only like calling applybindings once on loading the page, but that does mean that you need to have all the observables you want to bind to created on page load. You could create a child view model for bios, with the observables you want to bind too, and then always use the update fromJSON method to populate it.

Have you tried:

```
function biosViewModel()
{
    var self = this;
    self.Caption = ko.observable();
    self.Version = ko.observable();
}

var viewModel =
{
    bios: ko.observable(new biosViewModel()),
    cpu: ko.observable()
}
```

Then, in your success method:

```
ko.mapping.fromJSON(data, viewModel.bios());
```

to update the object with the data you get back from the server.

Comment: In this case I need to have some boolean variable to indicate if it is the very first call or not (and check it every time). The data isn't loaded on start - it's loaded only by user click. Is it a good way to solve this problem?

Comment: Yeah, or you could just check if(viewModel.bios()), that should be false if it doesn't have a value.

Comment: If I understand correctly I need to call applyBindings() one more time after the first usage. But it can erase the data which is contained in observableArrays, can't it?

Comment: Updated answer with my preferred way of dealing with this kind of situation.