# Trying to map array from JSON to knockout using mappings

Tags: javascript, json, knockout-2.0, knockout-mapping-plugin

Hi I have a JSON array like so

```
[{
    "id": "537901a53513fa3374bec718",
    "images": [],
    "itemImage": "img/3.jpg",
    "createdDate": "5/18/2014 6:53:25 PM",
    "location": [
        -2.057802,
        52.609711
    ]
},
{
    "id": "537901a53513fa3374bec710",
    "images": [
        "img/17.jpg"
    ],
    "itemImage": "img/1.jpg",
    "createdDate": "5/18/2014 6:53:25 PM",
    "location": [
        -2.062251,
        52.612397
    ]
}]
```

I'm trying to use the ko.mapping.fromJSON / JS, but i keep messing up sigh :(

```
  var viewModel = {};
```

in my Ajax success function,

```
  viewModel.model = ko.mapping.fromJSON(data);
  ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

HTML

```
   <div data-bind=" foreach: model">
       <div data-bind="text: body"></div>
   </div>
```

I've tried following this post answered by John Papa, but I think my array is different.
[Knockout JS mapping plugin confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8822943/knockout-js-mapping-plugin-confusion)
I can do it manually, but am bored of manually building view models :).

Also tried this and got confused further [Can't map JSON object to ViewModel (knockout js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413556/cant-map-json-object-to-viewmodel-knockout-js?rq=1)

Would any kind souls be able to point me in the right direction ?

Comment: Is the data actually a JSON string, or already a javascript object?  You may need to be using ko.mapping.fromJS instead

Comment: tried it with both, got it to partially work with JS, but the mapping was messed up so it only mapped one item to to a observable array, thx

Comment: I've just tested it using the objects declared above, and it seems fine.  I wonder if it may be the ajax call itself - can you debug and check that data contains what you expect before it gets passed to the ko mapping plugin?

Comment: Hi, data has not changed that's the output in fiddler, it's also valid JSON according to the validators out there !

Comment: so what does `viewModel.model` actually contain after the mapping?  Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: checked ie11 & Chrome and nada, great!

Comment: also nothing in mapped properties nothing  _KO_mapping_

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is the following:

```
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

You loop them as follows:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: $data">
            <tr>

                <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

See example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/wr5W7/5/

Comment: HI, Yeh tried this, but how do i access my array objects, i can see they exist in __KO_mapping_ in mapped properties , everything is there, the items are like this [0].body inside of mapped properties, how to iterate thru them in HTML with for each, that's kinda where i'm stuck

Comment: thx for that your code essentially works, for the sake of brevity i didn't include additional all the json, they are just strings anyway however the Id's display about 10/50 then a load of additional text appears although there's no HTML binding to it!!!, confused a little, I know $data is a built in this for arrays but cant reference it from code, isn't the whole point about mapping meant to be observables, and how do we access them after mapping in code as well as in HTML ?

Comment: @saj sorry not at a PC. You can reference the other properties of the observable with the property name. If you wish to add to the js object create a js function & map inside of it. Sorry if I haven't understood you correctly might be worth asking another question with new examples.

Comment: One Question. The bindings are applied each time the view model changes in your solution. how can we tackle that